# SQLite How can we access Database in other app

Tags: android, sqlite

I know it is possible to access `DataBase` which in `SDCARD` by many apps in android.

but do not know the process to do that.

1- I created one `test.db` DB in sdcard eclipse .

2- My current `app` is using this DB.

3- I created one `other app`(which ll access this DB)

**Please guide me How can i access test.db in my new app.**

Comment: Simple copy that `test.db` from sdcard to your Application's Internal package `/data/data/<package_name>/databases/` and use.

Comment: user if database modified than..again i need to copy

Comment: sorry user please provide me some permanent solution .means both app can fetch and write the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same database only if you created the running application database in custom content provider.

You cannot directly access the database from running application.

But if you create your running application database in Custom Content Provider then with the help of authorities you can directly access the database.

In this case you don't even need to copy that database.

Refer this [link](http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/custom-content-provider-in-android/) for custom content provider.

Comment: means i can not fetch the DB which in SD card with out content provider.

Comment: to do that i need to extends contentprovider not sqliteopenhelper in my DB class of first app..m i right

Comment: in your demo .where you are creating new app..its just single app in different packages